# I need check the extension of file using the regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check the extension of a file in a folder with a regular expression.

For example, .wmv and .WMV recognize the same word.

But how do you make .wmv and WMV recognize the same thing?

I am using this pattern now that '^[.]?[^.]+$'

In case of case, the input value is converted into lower case in code and compared.

How can we make wmv and WMV the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check file extension using following regex.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[.]?[^.]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

You don't need to convert input value to lower case for comparison, instead  you could use override of Regex that allows you to IgnoreCase.

Example : [Here](https://regex101.com/r/DrrrxA/4)

Comment: Thanks your help but it is not work using the one word.
here is a example https://regex101.com/r/DrrrxA/2

Comment: @HyunsooKim May be i misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to iignore cases where "." is not present. I have updated the answer. It uses your own regex, but with Regex.IgnoreCase.

Comment: @HyunsooKim Glad to help, kindly mark it as answer if it helped in resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

RegexOptions is working for you [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_).

```
public static System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match(string input, string pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options);
```

Eg:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And here are all the options you can use: [RegexOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2)